# Fetch logs using Heroku Platform API

Tags: logging, heroku

Using [Heroku Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) is it possible to fetch latest log messages for an app via HTTP request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to get what you want. You can get a log session via: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#log-session-create

You can use the logplex_url returned there to look up logs. If you just do a GET to that url you will probably get what you are after. Streaming them is not-quite HTTP, so things get a bit more complicated, but I think that should allow you to get the last few lines.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for